# How to focus an input field only when on a desktop browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, browser, focus

What is the best way to focus an input field *only* when the user is on a desktop browser?

I use jQuery and setting the focus is done like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").focus();
}
```

But now on mobile devices (e.g. phones and tablets), the on-screen keyboard appears. I would like to avoid that. I would also like to avoid browser sniffing. Any ideas?

PS: Fetching the browser viewport ist *not* a solution.

Comment: you cant actually get the screen resolution but you can get the height and width of the browser window (and that too is changeable by resizing the browser )

Comment: @MohammadAdil Rephrased it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so just with javascript by checking the UserAgent, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
      //mobile code
   } else {
      //desktop code
      $("input").focus();
   }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I would like to avoid browser sniffing.

Answer (score -1):

I'd try setting a flag on the serverside.  IE add a class to your parent div `'isDesktop'` then on the clientside, check for it like so

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     if($('.myParentDiv').hasClass('isDesktop')){
       $("input").focus();
}
    }
```

Another approach if you don't have access to the server side might be to user jquery's `$.browser` which gives you info about the browser.

Comment: Yes that is easy. But the hard part would be to identify a browser, while I would like to avoid any kind of browser sniffing.

Comment: jQuery.browser has been deprecated. And as I said, I would like to avoid browser sniffing.